# Thinks counter is a string, not an integer

Tags: python, types

I'm trying to extract the first few elements of a tab-delimited file using the following:

```
words = []
name_elements = []
counter = 0

for line in f:
    words = line.split()
    for element in words:
        counter = counter + 1
        if words[element].isupper():
           name_elements = words[0:counter-1]

print type(counter)
```

When I run this code, I get this error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
logout
```

Even though when I run type(counter) it says it's an integer.

What's the issue?

Comment: The error is here: `words[element]`, element is not an index, it's the value itself. Try using element directly.

Comment: Make sure you look at the line number given in the error.  Then you would have noticed the error was with `words[element]` and not `words[0:counter-1]`.

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to index `words` with `element`. `element` is a string; it is *already* the item you wanted to get.

The `for` loop is giving you each element from `words` in turn, assigning it to the `element` variable. `element` is not an integer index into the `words` list.

Note that your counter is going to go out of bounds; if you want to have an index into the `words` list along with the element, use the `enumerate()` function. You are also replacing the `name_elements` list with a slice from `words`; perhaps you wanted to extend the list instead:

```
for line in f:
    words = line.split()
    for counter, element in enumerate(words):
        if element.isupper():
            name_elements.extend(words[:counter-1])
```

although it is not clear exactly what you wanted to do with the `words` list in this case.